# Fullscreen Browser

Tags: linux, browser, fullscreen

I'm looking for a fullscreen browser for linux. It doesn't have to have any controls. It suffices if I can control the page on startup by passing a commandline argument.

If possible, I'd like to avoid any toolkits (like GTK).

There is no interaction needed. The website updates itself automatically.

Comment: Firefox in Ubuntu can work in full screen. Just press F11

Comment: in fullscreen you wont see the toolkit anyway ... so, whats the purpose of this fullscreen browser? only showing one page? interaction  needed?

Comment: @jap1968: Thanks for the hint. I'm looking for a more lightweight alternative if possible.

Comment: @akira: Yes, only showing one page (see my updated question above)

Comment: @SecStone: and do you want prevent folks from clicking around? or do you prevent this by not attaching a mouse / kbd to the machine?

Comment: @akira: Yes, I already prevent this by not attaching any input devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the browsers are particularly lightweight anymore due to the increasing number of formats and protocols they must support.

Chromium seems pretty self-contained though, and you can launch in full screen with the kiosk switch:

```
chromium --kiosk <url>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider [midori](http://twotoasts.de/index.php/midori/) to be a very lightweight browser which you can start in fullscreen mode like this:

```
midori -e Fullscreen
```

Passing the URL as an argument is a bit of a hassle so I decided to configure it as the start page and show that each time the browser gets started.