# A non-exitable (with a mouse) fullscreen mode in a web browser

Tags: browser, mouse, fullscreen

Let's imagine that I have some kind of a webpage which I want to display on a big screen in a public place. An interactive timetable, for example. I setup a computer, hide keyboard and leave the mouse near the screen so people could interact with the timetable (they don't need keyboard to to that, mouse is enough). I don't want them to exit the browser and jump into my OS. So I need some way to make the browser go fullscreen so it would not be obviously possible to leave the fullscreen mode using only mouse. Since they have no access to keyboard, I don't mind it being possible from keyboard (I actually need this to exit fullscreen mode myself, as an admin). I looked at Firefox and Chromium, but they both have the possibilities to exit fullscreen with a mouse (top menu/exit floater).

The question is: is there a modern browser that has no way to exit fullscreen mode with a mouse or that has an option to disable that possibility? Preferably the ones available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Search for "kiosk mode". See also [Kiosk software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software)

Comment: Found a solution https://superuser.com/questions/368439/fullscreen-browser?rq=1 `chromium --kiosk url.org`

Comment: Well, found a solution anyway. Do I need to delete the question now?

Comment: Good. It is better to leave it. I've voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Even though that question out there is considered off-topic, it was useful to me. *shrugs*